# Consecutive spaces in inline code get collapsed

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, inline-code

I’ve found a markdown bug:

```
To match three or more spaces in regex, use `/   +/`.
```

☞

> To match three or more spaces in regex, use `/   +/`.

Boom.

Comment: Sorry for the close/reopen/close. It is a dupe after all, but I disagree with the [tag:status-bydesign]. I'll fix it, it's a simple CSS change.

Comment: Setting to status-completed - this is in the next build.